# PATCH Service deserilizaition into JSON Object

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I'm building a PATCH service where I'm trying to deserlize into a JSON payload that has different levels.

```
{
    "ShippingAddress": {
        "Country": "United States",
        "PostalCode": "80202",
        "StateOrProvince": "CO",
        "Street": "Testing Street 123",
        "City": "Denver"
    },
    "BillingAddress": {
        "Country": "United States",
        "PostalCode": "80202",
        "StateOrProvince": "Colorado",
        "Street": "123 Main St 1122",
        "City": "Denver"
    },
    "Person": {
        "LastName": "Dan20140214c",
        "IsPrimary": true,
        "FirstName": "Dan20140214c",
        "Email": "Dan20140214c@inc.com",
        "Phone": "5511555555555",
        "MemberType": "Guest Traveler"
    },

    "MobilePhone": "5555555555 ",
    "DryFlyAccountID": 120919,
    "ActivePURL": "",
    "AccountParentID": ""
}
```

I'm trying to put this into a `Map<String, Object>  castedBody = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestBody);` which works for everything else but I need some guidance on how to traverse the nodes inside the object.  I have control over this service so I can flatten out the payload I'm just trying to make the payload as clean as possible.

When I deserialize it looks like this

> {AccountParentID=, ActivePURL=, BillingAddress={City=Denver, Country=United States, PostalCode=80202, StateOrProvince=Colorado, Street=123 Main St 1122}, DryFlyAccountID=120919, MobilePhone=5555555555 , Person={Email=Dan20140214c@inc.com, FirstName=Dan20140214c, IsPrimary=true, LastName=Dan20140214c, MemberType=Guest Traveler, Phone=9995959595}, ShippingAddress={City=Denver, Country=United States, PostalCode=80202, StateOrProvince=CO, Street=Testing Street 123}}

Comment: My personal preference is to keep JSON structures as flat as possible if they're representing a single object (as it looks like this does) to reduce the number of `containsKey()` checks you end up doing and the depth of your logic tree.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following

Create a custom ApexType that looks like:

```
public class Foo {
  ShippingAddress ShippingAddress;
  BillingAddress BillingAddress;
  Person Person;
  String MobilePhone;
  String DryFlyAccountId;
  String ActivePURL;
  String AccountParentId;

  public class ShippingAddress {
    String Country ;
    ...
  }
  public class BillingAddress {
    ...
  }
  public class Person {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then

```
Foo foo = (Foo) Json.deserialize(thePatchBody,Foo.class);
```

Comment: That would work for me if it wasn't a PATCH service, they won't be sending me fields if they aren't updated.. When I deserialzie into that class it would use all the properties. It would give me null/blanks when in reality they just didn't send the field because it wasn't updated.  When is why I'm using deserializedUntyped

Comment: @EricSSH - ah true, I interpreted OP that if Foo.Person was null, then you knew that Person wasn't updated but otherwise a Person would be sent in its entirety.